# Удаляется ли объект при присвоении ему значения null?

Tags: c#, c++-cli

Есть полу-нативный класс [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b)/[c++-cli](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b-cli), который управляется из [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23), при этом один из его элементов/составляющих классов, должен быть удален из памяти незамедлительно если ему было присвоено значение `null`, и мне теперь непонятно, если экземпляр данного класса не будет уничтожен, то все приложение упадет в один миг. Ведь если верить `GC`, то он удаляет экземпляр из памяти только в том случае когда он этого захочет, но мне необходимо именно удалить его в тот момент, когда было присвоено значение `null`. Понимаю что есть метод `Dispose()`, но его недостаточно, т.к. методы класса, и сам класс не должны быть доступны после их удаления, чего `Dispose()` не гарантирует, а плевать в лицо исключениями, это затормозить работу приложения.

Можно ли перегрузить оператор присваивания так, что бы как только было передано значение `null`, данные класс уничтожил ссылку на себя? **Желательно без помощи `GC`.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы не можете «уничтожить» экземпляр управляемого класса.
Присваивая ссылке `null`, вы тем самым не обнуляете другие возможные ссылки на объект. Соответственно, по другим ссылкам объект будет всё ещё доступен. Вызов `Dispose()` лишь позволяет объекту подчистить за собой, но это не приведёт к «запрету» другим объектам вызывать методы данного класса (и получать исключения). Обеспечить, чтобы у других объектов не было ссылок на ваш объект (или они были, но объекты ими бы не пользовались) — ваша задача.

Перегрузить оператор присваивания ссылки невозможно. Но даже если бы это было возможно, что бы вы в нём могли сделать? Те, у кого есть ссылка, будут всё ещё иметь эту ссылку.

---

Если это нативный класс, вы можете деаллоцировать его при помощи `delete` по указателю на него, но вы должны обеспечить, чтобы те, у кого всё ещё есть указатель на данный объект, более не пользовались им. Иначе вы получаете undefined behavior.

Comment: Получается что в любом из случаев, когда в управляемом коде я присвою значение "этому" классу значение `null`, `GC` ни в коем случае не станет его удалять? Даже если это будет принудительный вызов очистки памяти занимаемой данным объектом?

Comment: @Birdy: В том-то и дело, что вы присваиваете `null` не объекту, а лишь ссылке на него. Аналог из реальной жизни: вы вычеркнули адрес человека из своей записной книжки, но от этого человек никуда не делся. Ссылка — это своего рода адрес объекта.

Comment: вот блин, ну так то оно правильно, но я думал все таки если будет указан деструктор в полу-нативном коде, то когда ссылка на него получит значение null, он незамедлительно будет удален. А что если попробовать собрать все ссылки и уничтожить их принудительно, в методе `Dispose()`, это тоже не будет гарантировать то что он будет именно удален из памяти?

Comment: @Birdy: Ну, если вы найдёте все ссылки и обнулите их, то больше никто не сможет вызвать методы этого объекта. После этого объект когда-нибудь в будущем съест GC (может быть, никогда), так что если вам нужно уничтожение сразу **даже** при отсутствии ссылок на объект, вызовите `Dispose`.

Comment: Спасибо, буду пробовать данный вариант.